# specifying image width full size WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

how can I fix this issue on google chrome:

[image]

this is on my website (www.haagsehof.nl) when I try to test for the responsiveness. this is what happens.

it should look like this:
[image]

Even this one is not correct and as you can see the heads are missing. I think this is css problem inside WordPress. because I made this section in WordPress using custom HTML, as you can see here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
    html, body{  height: 100%; width:100%;}

   #pl-4 {
        background: url(https://www.haagsehof.nl/content/uploads/2018/02/20171120_Haagsehof_1300_blackoverlay.jpg) no-repeat center center;
        -webkit-background-size: 100%;
        -moz-background-size: 100%;
        -o-background-size: 100%;
        background-size: 100%;
        margin-left: -15px;
        margin-right: -15px;
    }


    @media only screen and (max-width: 399px) {
    #pl-4{
            background: url(https://www.haagsehof.nl/content/uploads/2018/03/15214591016010952.jpg) fixed  no-repeat center center ; 
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
            margin-left: -15px;
        margin-right: -15px;
        }
    }

    .wrapper{
            margin-top: 150px;
    }


    div, body{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: exo, sans-serif;
    }
    .wrapper {      height: 100%;       width: 100%;    }

    #headerSchoon{
        color: white !important;
        text-align: center !important;
    }
    #textSchoon{
        color: white !important;
        text-align: center !important;
        font-size: 150%;
    }
</style>

<body id="mainSchoonMaker">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo:400,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="message">
            <h1 id="headerSchoon">Schoonmaakwerk is mensenwerk</h1>
            <p id="textSchoon"> Wij willen door middel van een persoonlijke en mensgerichte aanpak betrokkenheid creëren tussen schoonmaakmedewerker, klant en schoonmaakbedrijf Haagsehof. Hierdoor ontstaat er een chemie die leidt tot een optimale dienstverlening, waarbij u als klant door ons en onze medewerkers volledig wordt ontzorgd.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

what is going wrong here, how can I display the full image that you can just scroll up and down and it has the same style for both telephone devices and normal computers? thanks a lot.

===EDIT===
after using this:

```
#pl-4 {
        background: url(https://www.haagsehof.nl/content/uploads/2018/02/20171120_Haagsehof_1300_blackoverlay.jpg) no-repeat center center;
        background-size: cover;
        margin-left: -15px;
        margin-right: -15px;
    }
```

suggested by @Ruben Pauwels, this is what happens, for mobile, the image is not complete, I dont understand why this is so difficult:
[image]

and this is for the mobile version how can I fix these issues, I have had several solutions but none seems to be able to fixing this issue:
[image]

Comment: in which size? seems already working fine?

Comment: @vel well, in the normal chrome window its fine, but when u make it smaller like for a mobile phone, then the image is gone (white background), and the text is also in white, in the normal chrome version the heads of the people in the photo is missing. and that is the problem can you see these things?

Comment: you need to change the background image in the div for mobile. I think already i said. do you have FTp access now?

Comment: @vel I have access to the server through cpanel!

Comment: you need to add some class to the center div.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the background-size property should fix your issue.
See here for more info: [MDN Background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

```
#pl-4 {
        background: url(https://www.haagsehof.nl/content/uploads/2018/02/20171120_Haagsehof_1300_blackoverlay.jpg) no-repeat center center;
        background-size: cover;
        margin-left: -15px;
        margin-right: -15px;
    }
```

Comment: The only way to (almost) get the full image in your div, is by enlarging your div. For mobile: Because of the aspect ratio of the image, it is not possible to get the full image -> You can get the full image, but the div will not be covered, or you can cover the div, but not the entire image will be visible.

Comment: I think it's fine if in the mobile version the whole image is not visible,As long as the two people in the middle are partly visible it's fine. Can I do that by resizing the image to a smaller size?

Comment: That would be a good idea to at least try. If you use `background-size:cover;` for your mobile version, it should work just fine.

Comment: @ Ruben Pauwels that didnt work, the background image is white, and when I do  `@media only screen and (max-width: 699px) {` itys shows the image but its zoomed in, I am using this verion of the image: ` https://www.haagsehof.nl/content/uploads/2018/03/20171120_haagsehof_1300_blacko-1.jpg `

Comment: Can you make an image in portret mode (e.g.: 700x1000)? This will suit your use-case better. The problem you are mentioning is due to the aspect ratio of the image.

Comment: @ Ruben Pauwels  can u clearify this : an image in portret mode. what do you eman exactly?

Comment: An image that's higher than it's width

Answer (score 0):

well, this is the best solution I could find, its not what I want but its at least better than what it is there now:
[image]

using:

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 780px) {
    #pl-4{
            background: url(https://www.haagsehof.nl/content/uploads/2018/03/15214591016010952.jpg)  ; 
            margin-left: -15px;
        margin-right: -15px;
background-size: contain;
/*max-width: 100%; 
max-height: 100%; */

        }
    }
```